# Convert a Queue to List

Tags: java, list, queue

What is the fastest way to convert a `Queue` into a `List` while keeping the Queue order?

Comment: `q.poll(), list.add()` ?

Comment: FYI this has issues when used with [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) read this  [Hacker Rank Case](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-priority-queue/forum/comments/487333 )  you will have to poll with loop to get it right in the list

Comment: @shareef I'm having the same issue. Took the whole evening for an actually easy problem.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The fastest is to use a LinkedList in the first place which can be used as a List or a Queue.

```
Queue q = new LinkedList();
List l = (List) q;
```

Otherwise you need to take a copy

```
List l = new ArrayList(q);
```

Note: When dealing with PriorityQueue, Use a loop, poll each element and add to list. PriorityQueue to List not maintaining the heap order.

Answer (score 13):

## Pass `Queue` To `ArrayList` Constructor

The easiest way to just create a [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and pass your [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) as an argument in the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-) of ArrayList that takes a [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html). A `Queue` is a `Collection`, so that works.

This is the easiest way and I believe fastest way too.

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<>( myQueue );
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, is it is the only one to directly address the Question. The Question referred to the [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) interface. There are many implementations of Queue, both bundled with Java and found in other libraries such as [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava). The other answers refer only to [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) which is but one of many implementations.

Answer (score 12):

If you're converting from **`PriorityQueue`** to a `List`, remember that it is in fact a heap, so the ordering is determined using the `poll()` method, in which case, doing it by the constructor way as discussed in some of the other answers here, won't preserve the natural ordering of the queue.

Taking that into consideration, you can go along these lines:

```
List<E> result = new ArrayList<>(yourPriorityQueue.size());
while (!yourPriorityQueue.isEmpty()) {
    result.add(yourPriorityQueue.poll());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Queue queue = new LinkedList();
...
List list = new ArrayList(queue);
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering to old question for users who are already on java 8
Java 8 provides the option of using streams and you can get a list from queue as:

For example:

```
Queue<Student> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        Student s1 = new Student("A",2);
        Student s2 = new Student("B",1);
        Student s3 = new Student("C",3);
        queue.add(s1);
        queue.add(s2);
        queue.add(s3);

    List<Student> studentList = queue.stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: If the queue is PriorityQ, then this streams methods preserves the order?

Answer (score 1):

Google:

```
Queue fruitsQueue = new LinkedList();
fruitsQueue.add("Apples");
fruitsQueue.add("Bananas");
fruitsQueue.add("Oranges");
fruitsQueue.add("Grapes");

List fruitsList = new ArrayList(fruitsQueue);
```